# How does a JLabel display an animated gifs so CPU efficiently?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, gif

The following code lets me show 10 big gif images with a cpu performance of roughly 5%

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("target.gif");
JLabel jp = new JLabel(image);
```

If I implement a similar function manually utilising the Open-Imaging library by DhyanB (https://github.com/DhyanB/Open-Imaging) it results in about a magnitude worse in performance.
I took a look at the JLabel, ImageIcon and JComponent source code but could not find the section responsible for displaying .gif files.
I want to figure out how it's done to see if I can do some efficient image manipulation before the gif animation is drawn.

```
GifImage gifImage = GifDecoder.read(new FileInputStream(f));
final int frameCount = gifImage.getFrameCount();

//Very basic gif playback
do{
    long lastUpdate = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++){
        BufferedImage frame = gifImage.getFrame(i);
        final int delay = (gifImage.getDelay(i))*10;

        //TODO Alpha masking and rescaling

        final long timePassedSinceLastFrame = (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdate); //Change to nanao if necessary

        final long sleep =  delay - timePassedSinceLastFrame;

        if(sleep > 0)
            Thread.sleep(sleep);

        //Display

        targetImage = frame;
        self.repaint();
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}while(loop);


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    if(targetImage != null){
        g.drawImage(targetImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code? I'd wager the problem is with your "very basic gif playback" which does unnecessary paints.

Comment: I have not profiled it depth, but calling repaint once for every frame is about as little painting as I can do. That is why I hope to take a look at the source code which is responsible for displaying gif files in JLabels.

Comment: So you haven't profiled it at all. No use in looking at the source code and guessing, when you can profile it and find out what's using the CPU. If you haven't used `jvisualvm` before, now's a good time to learn that too.

Comment: *"The following code lets me show 10 big gif images with a cpu performance of roughly 5%"* The Swing GUI engine is clever and will only render parts of an app. that are visible. So those '10 big gif images' can only ever be as big as the screen resolution. It's surprising to me that takes as much as 5% of a modern CPU, unless the GIF's have an insanely high frame rate.